# Can not seem to get Django to display the correct content in web-pages

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am creating a web-app using Django.  I want the app to have 4 sections, the homepage, Culture, Entertainment, and Technology.  The home page would display all the articles while the other pages would  display articles that relate to that category.  I created a class for all the articles.  Some of the class objects are: category, title, by, summary.  In views.py, for the homepage, I created a function to display all the articles in random order.   I then created 3 more functions that display the articles by category.  The problem is, the home page is the only one that works properly.  I made links to all 4 pages in my navbar, all four links go back to my homepage instead of the category pages i made.  The function I made for the homepage or all_blogs is the only one that works.  When I modify it so it only displays articles in a certain category it works, but when I try to make a new function and new page, it only displays the homepage.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Blog


def all_blogs(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.order_by('?')
    return render(request, 'blog/all_blogs.html', {'blogs': blogs})


def Entertainment(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.exclude(category='Technology, Culture')
    return render(request, 'blog/Entertainment.html', {'blogs': blogs})


def Technology(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.exclude(category='Entertainment, Culture')
    return render(request, 'blog/Technology.html', {'blogs': blogs})


def Culture(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.exclude(category='Entertainment, Technology')
    return render(request, 'blog/Culture.html', {'blogs': blogs})


def pageOne(request, blog_id):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)
    return render(request, 'blog/pageOne.html', {'blog': blog})


def all_blogsT(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.order_by('category')
    return render(request, 'blog/pageOne.html', {'blogs': blogs})
```

all_blogs.html

```
{% extends 'blog/navBarFooter.html' %}
{% block content %}
<br>
<br>
{% for blog in blogs %}
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-8">
    <img src="{{ blog.summaryImage.url }}" height=190 width=350>
    <p>{{ blog.category }}</p>
    <a href="{% url 'pageOne' blog.id %}">
        <h2>{{ blog.title }}</h2>
    </a>
    <p>By: {{ blog.by }} | {{ blog.date|date:'M d Y'|upper }}</p>
    <p>{{ blog.summary }}</p>
    <hr color="black">
</div>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Entertainment.html

```
{% extends 'blog/navBarFooter.html' %}
{% block content %}
<br>
<br>
{% for blog in blogs %}
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-8">
    <img src="{{ blog.summaryImage.url }}" height=190 width=350>
    <p>{{ blog.category }}</p>
    <a href="{% url 'pageOne' blog.id %}">
        <h2>{{ blog.title }}</h2>
    </a>
    <p>By: {{ blog.by }} | {{ blog.date|date:'M d Y'|upper }}</p>
    <p>{{ blog.summary }}</p>
    <hr color="black">
</div>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

navBarFooter.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
{% load static %}
<!-- **********NAVBAR**************************** -->

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Russo+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/xworld.css' %}">

</head>

<body>
    <nav class=" navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark justify-content-end">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'all_blogs' %}">home.com</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'Culture' %}">Culture</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'Entertainment' %}">Entertainment</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'Technology' %}">Technology</a>
                </li>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from blog import views
    
urlpatterns = [
   

     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', views.all_blogs, name='all_blogs'),
        path('entertainment/', views.Entertainment, name='Entertainment'),
        path('technology/', views.Technology, name='Technology'),
        path('culture/', views.Culture, name='Culture'),
        path('<int:blog_id>/', views.pageOne, name='pageOne'),
        ]
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Where ur url.py

Comment: updated question with urls.py

Comment: Your homepage has the same url path with entertainment , technology and culture... so when you go to any one it will go to first matching path which is the all blog page

Answer (score 0):

Your urls can't all be the same as your website would go to first one it finds, which is `all_blogs`. Give your urls unique paths like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from blog import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.all_blogs, name='all_blogs'),
    path('entertainment/', views.Entertainment, name='Entertainment'),
    path('technology/', views.Technology, name='Technology'),
    path('culture/', views.Culture, name='Culture'),
    path('blog/<int:blog_id>/', views.pageOne, name='pageOne'),
]
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, I added a unique path to each url and updated the original question.  The home page is working like it should.  However, instead of just displaying the objects that have have a specific category, the other pages display all the objects in the same order.  They are listed,   Entertainment, Technology, Culture, the same order I have the url patterns.  How do I make it so just the objects in a specific category show up.

Comment: Check to see if your querysets are returning the correct things. Try using `filter` instead of `exclude` like `blogs = Blog.objects.filter(category='Entertainment')`. If you do want to use exclude, I believe it takes a list; right now it is just seeing `category='Technology, Culture'` as a string. It might help to post your models.py

Comment: thank you again, filter achieved the desired affect.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this

```
path('', views.all_blogs, name='all_blogs'),
path('entertainment/', views.Entertainment, name='Entertainment'),
path('technology/', views.Technology, name='Technology'),
path('culture/', views.Culture, name='Culture'),
```